# Determining XPath

Tags: c#, xpath

Total XPath noob here and it doesn't help that I have only a basic grounding in HTML/XML (Infrastructure support is my domain). Please could you help me determine a good XPath for the highlighted value (2nd Line Engineer). I managed to it for "description", extracting the text value underneath by using:

```
//div[@class='description'
```

but am unable to do so for the mentioned one. Also how does one target the below node in a statement?

```
"li class="position" data-section="currentPositionDetails"
```

[image]

Comment: If you read [ask], there's usually a bit of an expectation that you do some research before asking a question.  Sticking 'XPath tutorial' into google would get you things like [this site](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp), which would get you a long way to solving this.

Comment: Noted. And improving knowledge in this area as we speak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some possible solutions:

```
//li[@data-section='currentPositionsDetails']
//li[@data-section='currentPositionsDetails']//*[@class='item-title']//text()
//li[@data-section='currentPositionsDetails']//*[@class='item-title']//span/text()
```

Comment: Hi, this seems plausible to me but not getting any data returned. Here is an example link: https://www.linkedin.com/in/charlie-martindale-1691a2121?authType=name&authToken=r1_K&trk=prof-sb-browse_map-name. I'm using a tool called the HTMLAgilityPack XPath finder which can be used to check a query : https://hapxpathfinder.codeplex.com/

Comment: try now, missed an 's' , used currentPositionDetails instead of currentPositionsDetails

Comment: That'll be it! Thanks a bunch :)